# Насколько целесообразна такая функция?

Tags: php

```
function security($value)
{
    if (is_array($value) == true) {
        $itog = array();
        foreach ($value as $b => $c) {
            $itog[$b] = htmlspecialchars($c);
        }
    } else {
        $itog = htmlspecialchars($value);
    }
    return $itog;
}
```

Т.е. если, например, форма, которую заполнил пользователь, записывается в базу и в ней много полей (а точнее неизвестно сколько, т.к можно добавить кнопкой) и дабы не получить xss, т.к админ открыл ее, может потерять куки.

Как ее можно улучшить? Оптимизировать. Например, она не обработает многомерный массив.
Просто подумал, что дабы не допустить оплошность проще прогнать пост массив сразу. Ее же модификацию можно использовать перед добавлением в базу, заменив на `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function security($value) {
    if (is_array($value)){
            foreach($value as $b => $c)
            $value[$b]=security($c);
    }else{
        $value = strip_tags($value);
        }
        return $value;
}
```

Вообщем вот ф-я которая обработает массив любой вложенности. Забыл я что-то про рекурсию совсем)

Подсказали на форуме.. Гениально =)

```
function security($a) {
    return (is_array($a) ? array_map('security', $a) : strip_tags($a));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё нормально, при добавлении — **`mysql_real_escape_string()`**, при выводе — **`htmlspecialchars()`**.

Answer (score 0):

А откуда у вас возьмется многомерный массив если данные поступают из формы с неизвестным количеством идентичных элементов, и сюда же: откуда у вас возьмется единичное значение, если данные в $_POST массиве? Или я что-то не правильно понял?

я бы советовал привести код в порядок: адекватно назвать переменные и избавиться от тавтологии в условии

Что касается обработки данных - я бы советовал производить ее в методах работающих с бд. Но я могу ошибаться.

Comment: Форма такая:
5 полей на данные пользователя.
Потом х полей на товары.
например  размер,вес,цвет 
Нажимая кнопку [+]  мы можем добавить сколь угодно много полей для товара.
Имя у них задано так :  color[]  size[]
т.е получая форму мы имеем
в пост такой массив :

[fio] => 112312
[phone] => 21212
[url] => Array
[size] => Array
   (
     [0] => 2
     [1] => 5
   )

Comment: И его нам нужно прогнать.
А отвод не для массива там сделан чтобы ф-я была универсальна. И массив можно и нет. Я привел пример типовой ф-и, а если бы мне надо было провести больше 1 манипуляции над массивом? (убрать теги+транслит) то использование 1 ф-и которая будет использоваться часто в коде лучше чем каждый эллемент массива отдельно проверять или цикл в коде.

Comment: Насчет использовать в методах работающих с бд можно, но т.к ЦМС Дле я так подумал лучше не трогать родные классы работы с БД, а в спец файле функций добавить. И при обновлении движка не придется заного добавлять, и универсальность большая.  Может быть 100 таких в-й Одна удаляет теги, вторая экранирует, третья слеширует. В зависимости от того куда эти данные потом пойдут)